# Changing the order of event handling in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, page-lifecycle

I am creating an ASP.NET application which contains an update panel and adds components to it dynamically at runtime. I will have a button which the user clicks to add new fields to the update panel, however, I face a problem in that server controls can only be added to the update panel in Page_Init or Page_Load methods, and page execution will not reach the button click event handler until after these methods have been executed.

Is there any way that the button click event could be handled before Page_Load (but still after the postback data is available)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086320/dynamic-created-controls-inside-updatepanel

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood what you are actually trying to do. The answer is **no**. The [asp.net lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is specific.

Hope I helped!